# referencing outlets with new view controller table view

Tags: ios, swift

I've an button in my storyboard's main view. now I need to open an new table view in new screen when this button will be clicked. For this, I've

```
1. dragged an new view controller in the empty space on storyboard.
2. dragged an table view inside this new viewcontroller.
```

now not able to define this new table view in ViewController.swift. ctrl + drag from table view to ViewController.swift not opening any dialog.

any idea what wrong am I doing here.....

Comment: Its hard to say without much more details. When you control-drag from your table view onto the source file that defines the view controller it should display a popover that lets you create a new outlet for the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the details you have given, it looks like you have not set your viewController Class. Create a custom view controller class. Specify this class as the custom class in the Attributes inspector for the viewController scene and try adding your tableView.

Comment: yes, Thanks. This worked for me. stucked from 1 day. save my life.

Comment: can U help me once more. I've connected the table view with ViewController.swift. the problem is I can't access the array in table view funtion  which was initialized in the same ViewController.swift

Comment: Hello - r u here now?

Comment: Yes, i am here ---------------

Comment: No , i am not familiar with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120909/discussion-between-ripa-and-renjithr).